# Integration of partial derivative $\frac{dL}{dq}$ with respect to $t$ where $q$ is implicitly a function of $t$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics, calculus-of-variations

Is $\int_{t1}^{t2} \frac{\partial L}{\partial q}\delta{q} dt$ equal to $\left[\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}\delta{q}\right]_{t1}^{t2} $ if      $q$ implicitly depends on $t$  ? If not I misunderstood the derivation, if yes then why?

Comment: Are you asking why $\frac{d}{dq}\int Fdx = \int \frac{dF}{dq}dx$?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. Our math lecturer hasn't really delved into this yet and our physics lecturer is moving fast and this textbook(Landau) makes every step seem so trivial(maybe it would be for a veteran mathematician, but I'm clearly not yet one. See the first derivation of the E-L legrange equation on this page http://wiki.math.toronto.edu/TorontoMathWiki/index.php/Euler-Lagrange_Equation

Comment: I suggest you to use formula to formulate your question. It is hard to answer that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus)**

The fundamental theorem of calculus states there exists a function, an antiderivative, such that the following is true:

$$
\text{for } \int_a^b f(x) dx \text{, there exists } F(x) \text{, such that } f(x) = F'(x) \text{, that is}
$$

$$
\int_a^b f(x) dx = \int_a^b F'(x)dx = F(b) - F(a) 
$$
**Some Preliminaries ($G$ as the Antiderivative):**

When we have a multivariate function, then the above integral depends on the *other* variables, for instance:

$$
\int_a^bF(x, v)dx = g(v)
$$

where $g(v)$ is some function of the velocity--given different velocities, the integral will take on different values.

We know that there must exist an antiderivative, $G(x, v)$, for $F(x, v)$ such that $\frac{dG}{dx} = F(x, v)$:

$$
\frac{d}{dx}G(x, v) = \frac{\partial G}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial G}{\partial v}\frac{dv}{dx}
$$

Therefore:

$$
F(x, v) = \frac{\partial G}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial G}{\partial v}\frac{dv}{dx}
$$

**Relating $G(x, v)$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}$:**

\begin{align}
F(x, v) =&\ \frac{d}{dx} G(x, v) = \frac{\partial G}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial G}{\partial v}\frac{dv}{dx} \\ 
\frac{\partial F}{\partial v} =&\ \frac{\partial }{\partial v} \frac{d}{dx} \frac{\partial G}{\partial v} \\
=& \frac{\partial }{\partial v}\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial G}{\partial v}\frac{dv}{dx}\right)\\
=& \frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial v\partial x} + \frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial v^2}\frac{dv}{dx} + \frac{\partial G}{\partial v}\frac{\partial \frac{dv}{dx}}{\partial v} \\
=& \frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial v\partial x} + \frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial v^2}\frac{dv}{dx}
\end{align}

($\frac{\partial \frac{dv}{dx}}{\partial v} = 0$ because we should have $v = v(x)$ and thus no dependence on $v$--hopefully this is trivial to see)

**Relating $\frac{\partial }{\partial v}\int Fdx$ and $\frac{\partial G}{\partial v}$:**

The integral ($\frac{\partial G}{\partial v}$ is the antiderivative):

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\int\limits_a^b F(x, v) dx =&\ \frac{\partial}{\partial v}\left(G(b, v) - G(a, v)\right) = \frac{\partial G}{\partial v}(b, v) - \frac{\partial G}{\partial v}(a, v) 
\end{align}

Finding integrand for the antiderivative $\frac{\partial G}{\partial v}$:

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial G}{\partial v} =&\ \frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial x \partial v} + \frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial v^2} \frac{dv}{dx}
\end{align}

Putting this all together we have shown:

\begin{align}
\int_a^b \frac{\partial F}{\partial v}dx =&\ \int_a^b \left(\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial v\partial x} + \frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial v^2}\frac{dv}{dx}\right)dx \\
\frac{\partial }{\partial v}\int_a^b Fdx =&\ \int_a^b \left(\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial G}{\partial v}\right)dx = \int_a^b \left(\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial x\partial v} + \frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial v^2}\frac{dv}{dx}\right)dx 
\end{align}

Since $\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial x\partial v} = \frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial v\partial x}$ for "well behaved" $G(x, v)$, these two integrals are equal and thus:

$$
\int_a^b \frac{\partial F}{\partial v}dx = \frac{\partial }{\partial v}\int_a^b Fdx \text{, q.e.d}
$$

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question just now, it might've been for nothing , but the LateX will definitely prove useful in the future. We've definitely done the Fundamental theorem of calculus, but not the second part where you describe how it works for partial derivatives so I'll read through that and see if it answers my question. Thanks! (y)

Comment: @IanNeethling: If you think that the answer is good enough, you can upvote and accept the answer (that's a form of appreciation in this site).

Comment: Using Jared's method leaves me with $\int Ldt$ to evaluate , which is actually where the entire proof starts, but I guess I learnt something :/ PS: I can't upvote yet.